# Need help regarding htaccess pretty url

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, friendly-url

My `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [NC,L]

RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)$ index.php?page=$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)/$ index.php?page=$1 [QSA,L]
```

I have defined one key in the URL i.e. "page", which is working fine. Now I need to include a 2nd key but the "key" will be different for every page.

For example:

- `example.com/index.php?page=user?id=john`
- `example.com/index.php?page=product?url=product-url`

need to convert them to:

- `example.com/user/john`
- `example.com/product/product-url`

How can I define individual second keys based on page?

Comment: Without example of what you want, difficult to answer!

Comment: have added an example, hope now its more clear to you

Comment: May just be a typo, but since you've made the same mistake twice it's probably worth clarifying... you can only have one `?` in the URL. So, `/index.php?page=user?id=john` should obviously be `/index.php?page=user&id=john` (and likewise for your other example). Also, you should really decide on whether your URLs end with a slash or not, rather than allowing both (which is potentially "duplicate content" and detrimental to SEO). If you must then _redirect_ one to the other.

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [NC,L]

RewriteRule ^user/([^/]+)/?$ index.php?page=user&id=$1 [NC,QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^product/([^/]+)/?$ index.php?page=product&url=$1 [NC,QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)/?$ index.php?page=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Comment: Yeah this load data but links to css, js and images breaks.

Comment: url- example.com/css/custom.css  ,,becomes, example.com/user/css/custom.css

Comment: Use absolute links  (with `/` before) in your pages, `/css/custom.css` or add `<base href="/">` in html head. It's impossible to avoid, because with your rewrite, you change the location of the root